# Excel output articles list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm working in Excel with an article file. I'll let it contain article number (ex. 1001) and the amount of this article. Here is the problem: I want to put out all articles in one row, separated by comma's, I explain:

If I have a column with amount and a column with article number, I want a cell with output like this: 3 article's 1001 gives: 1001, 1001, 1001 .

I've got about 1000 articles and now I'm working with: =IF(B3=0, "", B3=1, "1001", B3=2, "1001, 1001"), but as you see this won't work.

I'm sorry for explaining, it's really hard with my broken English ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based off of your example I believe this formula will help you:

```
=REPT("1001,",B3)
```

**Update Per Comment**

To dynamically use C3 use the concatenation character `&`

```
=REPT(C3 & ",", B3)
```

This reads: Join the value of `C3` with the `,` and then repeat that `B3` times.

Comment: Okay thanks, I think it's near! because I can't fill in 1001 times that in the formule. So let's say C3 got the article number.

=REPT("C3,", B3) doesn't work, how to fix the C3? Thanks for now :D